# Xamarin Forms - Droid: Custom Picker's Dialog causing Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nullreferenceexception

**Background Description**

I am developing a cross platform mobile application using Visual Studio for Mac. The Xamarin.Forms version of the project is 3.1.0.583944 (which is the latest available). For Android all the entry components have a line instead (____________) of a box, and for this reason (and as a requirement) a custom render to change the component's appearance was created.

In the Project folder the CustomPicker.cs was created:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public class CustomPicker : Picker
    {
        public Color BorderColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

And in the Project.Droid folder the CustomPickerRenderer.cs was created:

```
using System;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Views;
using Project;
using Project.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace Project.Droid
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                var customPicker = (CustomPicker)e.NewElement;
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                gd.SetStroke(2, customPicker.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
                this.Control.SetBackground(gd);
                this.Control.SetTextColor(e.NewElement.TextColor.ToAndroid());
                this.Control.SetHintTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The xaml file contains just the CustomPicker element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:signature="clr-namespace:SignaturePad.Forms;assembly=SignaturePad.Forms"  xmlns:res="clr-Project" x:Class="Poject.View"  xmlns:local="clr-Project;assembly=Project">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <local:CustomPicker x:Name="action_picker" TextColor="Black" Title="Seleccione la acción" BorderColor="#3D7C00" IsEnabled="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding text}" SelectedIndexChanged="OnActionChange" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAction}" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Problem**

When testing the custom picker I get the desired results; the picker is rendered correctly with a box-like border instead of the underline and with some other color stuff. The component works as expected only when the "desired" functionality is tested (clicking the component, waiting for the dialog to pop up with the options, clicking an option, and clicking ok button). The problem occurs when for any reason the dialog is interrupted. For example, I click the component and while the options dialog pop up is appearing I click in the back button - then the dialog shows in another view and when tapping on an option or button then an exception is thrown. (Another scenario happens while the dialog is opening and I slide the screen from the top to open the configuration and notifications menu and then return to the app). The exception StackTrace is the following:

> UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0
>   (System.Object s, Android.Content.DialogClickEventArgs a) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\PickerRenderer.cs:135
>
> ```
> at Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick
> ```
>
> (Android.Content.IDialogInterface dialog, System.Int32 which)
>   [0x0000a] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/5809/a7829590/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-27/mcw/Android.Content.IDialogInterface.cs:250
>
> ```
> at Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_content_DialogInterface_I
> ```
>
> (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_dialog, System.Int32 which) [0x00010] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/5809/a7829590/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-27/mcw/Android.Content.IDialogInterface.cs:201
>
> ```
> at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.b72d5cd8-e4b0-403b-a87c-7a28c7960847(intptr,intptr,intptr,int)
> ```

**What's been tried**

Searching in the web I've found many possible solutions, but unfortunately none worked for me:

- [Updating Xamarin.Forms](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43965)
- [Adding AppCompat to Assembly](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1830)
- Adding a try - catch to the OnElementChanged function.
- Other possible solutions I don't even remember and can't find the link to them (as I opened a large amount of links).

**Questions**

1. How can this exception can be handled?
2. Is the custom picker renderer implementation possible without this crash or will I be forced to use the original component?
3. Is there a way I can access the OnClick event described in the error stack (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.)?

Any help in this issues is kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance to everyone who will take the time to read this long post and try to help.

Comment: On Android you could implement the OnClick event with the SetOnClickListener in your custom renderer, there is an example here: https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/Droid/Renderers/BindablePickerRendererDroid.cs

Comment: Thanks @hichame.yessou, and sorry for late reply. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Thunderlight did you have any luck resolving this ?  We are occasionally getting the same crash.

Comment: @mikecamimo what I did was to remove the custom picker and use the default one. Later I realized that the crashes happened due to the dialogs. So what I did was to check if the app was in background before showing the dialog (so it will only be shown when the app is currently active in foreground). I just added a flag on the onStart, onStop, onPause, and onResume methods to check the current state of the app. Doing this prevented the app to crash whenever the dialog appearance was interrupted. I hope this will help you. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: @Thunderlight Do you have any guaranteed steps to reproduce the problem, even if artificially (with delays etc) ? Try as I might, I'm unable to reproduce the crash on demand, yet I see a few users get it every day.

Comment: @mikecamimo the guaranteed steps to reproduce is to perform the event (let's say a click) to pop up a dialog, or a picker in this case, and before it opens, press the home button, or swip down for notifications, any event that will interrupt the dialog from showing just after the event was triggered.

Comment: @Thunderlight Try as I might, I'm still struggling to reproduce the crash, yet we are still seeing about 1% of users getting them in our appcenter crash logs. I even tried loading up our picker with thousands of items. The picker comes up so fast that its difficult to press another button before it pops up. Do you have a lot of items in your picker list ?  Can you please elaborate on how you used a flag in your on.... events ?

Comment: I've finally been able to reproduce the issue. In my case, I had the picker popping up, but I did not disable the navigation bar at the bottom of the page. Someone could popup the picker, but before it displayed they could choose another page from the navigation bar. This would replace the current page with a different one, and when they selected an item from the picker that was still visible it would cause the exception because the page no longer existed. Thanks for your help @Thunderlight :)

Comment: @mikecamimo Sorry I couldn't answer right away, but I am glad you could reproduce the issue. To answer your previous question I didn't have many items in my picker, but what worked for me was to deploy the app in a low-budget mobile phone (which is obviously slower) and that gave me the chance to interrupt the event, and cause the crash. If you get to solve the issue please let me know the way how you achieved this please. Also you're welcome, happy I could help you.

Comment: @mikecamimo About the second question I handled the flags in the App.cs file like this: 

`protected override void OnStart() { Global.AppInBackground = false; }`
`protected override void OnSleep() { Global.AppInBackground = true; }`
`protected override void OnResume() { Global.AppInBackground = false; }`

And when showing the popup just checked the flag to know whether the app is in foreground or background. Hope this helps you.